# sort elements with ordered number using list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

so i'm trying to learn list comprehensions in python, is it possible to sort the values of the elements with consecutive / ordered numbers? given the following data something like this

```
basket = {
    "basket1": [
        {"type": "Fruit", "name": "Melon"},
        {"type": "Goods", "name": "Hershey Bar"},
        ....
    ],
    "basket2": [
        {"type": "Fruit", "name": "Watermelon"},
        {"type": "Goods", "name": "Mineral"},
        ....
    ],
}
```

my result so far:

```
1. Fruit
1.1 Melon
1.3 Watermelon
2. Goods
2.2 Hershey Bar
2.4 Mineral
```

and the expected result like this:

```
1. Fruit
1.1 Melon
1.2 Watermelon
2. Goods
2.3 Hershey Bar
2.4 Mineral
# and so on
```

for the attempts that i've tried is like this.

```py
def object():
    data = basket["basket1"] + inventory["basket2"]

    # using list comprehensions
    fruits = [
        f"1.{i} {x['name']} \n" for i, x in enumerate(data, 1) if x["type"] == "Fruit"
    ]
    goods = [
        f"2.{i} {x['name']} \n" for i, x in enumerate(data, 1) if x["type"] == "Goods"
    ]

    if fruits and goods:
        print("1. Fruit: " + to_string(fruits))
        print("2. Goods: " + to_string(goods))
```

Thanks a lot for any support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about sorting first and rename it in a second step?

```
fruit = []
goods = []
for item in basket.values():
    for element in item:
        if element['type'] == 'Fruit':
            fruit.append(element['name'])
        elif element['type'] == 'Goods':
            goods.append(element['name'])
        else:
            pass

fruit = [f"1.{i} {x}" for i, x in enumerate(fruit, 1)]
good = [f"2.{i} {x}" for i, x in enumerate(goods, len(fruit)+1)]

print("1. Fruit:\n" + '\n'.join(fruit))
print("2. Goods:\n" + '\n'.join(good))

>>>
1. Fruit:
1.1 Melon
1.2 Watermelon
2. Goods:
2.3 Hershey Bar
2.4 Mineral
```

Comment: I already tried this method, but the result its still the same, the result that i expected is something like this `1.1 1.2 2.3. 2.4`, not `1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2`

Comment: In the line `good = [...]` just write `enumerate(goods, len(fruit)+1)`. Please see the edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use another list comprehension in you list comprehensions:

```
def object():
    data = basket["basket1"] + basket["basket2"]

    # using list comprehensions
    fruits = [
        f"1.{i} {x['name']} \n" for i, x in enumerate([d for d in data if d["type"] == "Fruit"], 1)
    ]
    goods = [
        f"2.{i} {x['name']} \n" for i, x in enumerate([d for d in data if d["type"] == "Goods"], 1)
    ]

    if fruits and goods:
        print("1. Fruit: " + to_string(fruits))
        print("2. Goods: " + to_string(goods))
```

A more efficient way would be using generator expression:

```
def object():
    data = basket["basket1"] + basket["basket2"]

    # using list comprehensions
    fruits = [
        f"1.{i} {x['name']} \n" for i, x in enumerate((d for d in data if d["type"] == "Fruit"), 1)
    ]
    goods = [
        f"2.{i} {x['name']} \n" for i, x in enumerate((d for d in data if d["type"] == "Goods"), 1)
    ]

    if fruits and goods:
        print("1. Fruit: " + to_string(fruits))
        print("2. Goods: " + to_string(goods))
```

Comment: yeah, i think its more efficient (and i also didn't notice if i can use list comprehension in another list comprehensions) but, the result that i expected is something like this `1.1 1.2 2.3. 2.4`, not `1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a given representation of your data.
First put your data in a more practical format given your needs, then print them according to the desired format.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# a dictionary which elements are initialized as lists by default
data = defaultdict(list)

# group data by type (Good, Fruits, ...)
for items in baskets.values():
    for item in items:
        data[item['type']].append(item['name'])
        
print(data)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Fruit': ['Melon', 'Watermelon'], 'Goods': ['Hershey Bar', 'Mineral']})
```

```
# Print the data with the wanted format
for i,(k,v) in enumerate(data.items()):
    print(f"{i+1} {k}")
    for j,item in enumerate(v):
        print(f"{i+1}.{j+1} item")
```

```
1 Fruit
1.1 item
1.2 item
2 Goods
2.1 item
2.2 item
```

Answer (score -1):

hi and welcome to python, you are going to have the time of your life!
is it possible you ask? the answer is 99.9% yes. let see how:
first lets try to change strategy of how we provide the answer.
instead of passing through the entire baskets, let first sort them to different lists and then enumerate them.

```py
    def sort_it(baskets):
        aggregate = defaultdict(list)
        for _, items_list in basket.items():
            for item in items_list:
                aggregate[item["type"]].append(item["name"])

        for title, values, idx in enumerate(addregate.items(), 1):
            print(f"{idx}. {title}: ")
            for item, num on enumerate(values):
                print("{idx}.{num} item")
```